# How can I add UITextField programmatically on top of a Google maps view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, uitextfield, subview

I am trying to create a custom UITextField and add it on top of a GoogleMaps View (GMSMapView)
It worked but the TextField is not responding to the touch event. What am I doing wrong? my code is:

```
[self.mapView_ insertSubview:searchTextView atIndex:0];
[self.mapView_ bringSubviewToFront:searchTextView];
```

The textfield is visible on top of the mapview but not responding at all.

Comment: Not related to the problem but your code could be simplified to `[self.mapView_ addSubview:searchTextView];` which adds the view on top of every other (existing) subview. Did you try to add the textView in the view that hosts the mapView instead?

Comment: Yes i did that too, the textField is visible but not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google Maps view has a BlockingGestureRecognizer.
You need to remove that - worked for me.

See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609357/1755778