# Unable to click on Textfield on GMaps for iOS Subview

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a searchbar (like in the Google Maps App for iOS).

So to look like the same as in that App, ill created a UITextField.

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    /* Add Google Map */

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(49.077872,longitude: 19.450339, zoom: 17)
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    self.view = mapView
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.indoorDisplay.delegate = self
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 64, 0)
    mapView.setMinZoom(15, maxZoom: 19)

    // add Searchbar 

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    searchTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(16, 50, screenWidth - 32, 40))
    searchTextField.delegate = self
    searchTextField.placeholder = "Gebäude und Räume suchen"
    searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.customGrey().CGColor
    searchTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)

    let showCategories = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    showCategories.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    showCategories.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithCode("fa-calendar-plus-o"), forState: .Normal)
    showCategories.setTitleColor(UIColor.customDarkGrey(), forState: .Normal)
    showCategories.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
    showCategories.addTarget(self,action: "calendarAddButtonPressed",forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    searchTextField.rightView = showCategories
    searchTextField.rightViewMode = .Always
    searchTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true

    self.mapView.addSubview(searchTextField)
```

The Button works fine, but i am unable to focus on the TextField.

When ill set (in ViewDidLoad).

```
searchTextField.becomesFirstResponder()
```

The Keyboard is there.

Also that event:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("start searching")
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Is not fireing.

Any ideas? When the SubView is not on the top level - the button should not work too, or?

Comment: try to add textfield on self.view not in map view.

Comment: try once this `self.view.addSubview(searchTextField)`, it  works or not

Comment: @Dhanas - already tried - but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ill found a solution for someone who is struggling with the same problems.

When you set:

```
self.view = mapView
```

It looks like that you are unable to set ANY subviews, because that Views never receive touch events.

So in that case use:

```
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Then all SubViews work fine.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer didn't help me at all, but it turns out there's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015266/ios-google-maps-textfield-not-responding)  on SO that is similar, but with Objective C. 
All `GMSMapView`s have a `GMSBlockingGestureRecognizer` by default, and that is why your textField isn't working the way you want it to. The solution is to remove it, so you can put this in your `viewDidLoad()` method:

**Swift 3**

```
for gesture in mapView.gestureRecognizers! {
    mapView.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

Alternatively, if you for some reason added other gesture recognizers to the mapView, you can do this:

```
for (index,gesture) in mapView.gestureRecognizers!.enumerated() {
    if index == 0 {
        mapView.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

Since the `GMSBlockingGestureRecognizer` is added by default, it will always be the first one in the array of gesture recognizers.

Also, **make sure** you put the for loop somewhere it will only be called once because if it is called multiple times, you could remove other gestures unintentionally.